# Silverlight datagrid scrollbar size is wrong

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, popup

I've got a Silverlight user control that contains a datagrid.  The datagrid is bound to an ObservableCollection.  The user control is displayed in a popup window that I show in response to some event in another control

There are about 80 objects in the collection, and I've set a fixed height of 400 on the datagrid, so only about 20 items can be shown at one time, and the vertical scrollbar should be shown, with a thumb size occupying about 1/4th of the control height.

However, what's **actually** happening is that the scrollbar occupies almost the whole control height; maybe 95% of it.  The datagrid displays the first 20 items.  When I click on the scrollbar down arrow, the scrollbar moves down a little to occupy the **bottom** 95% of the scroll area, and the datagrid displays the **last** 20 items.

It gets weirder.  If I move over the items in the grid and scroll down using the **mouse wheel**, then the items scroll correctly and I can view the whole list, although the scrollbar remains the same size.

And **then**, if I close the popup and reopen it, the scrollbar now appears with the correct height and it works correctly.

Finally, if I just show the control directly on the page, and **not** in a popup, it works fine.
What's going on here?!  Has anyone else run into this problem?  Help!

**Update**: The problem seems to be the way that I'm showing the popup.  For various reasons, I had to implement the popup display in a somewhat tricky way, and it's this that's causing the trouble.

Comment: can you isolate the problem and post the xaml and code? (without the 80 row data objects)

Comment: Not readily, but as I was trying to, I got closer to the source of the problem (see update), so danke schoën for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, but not in a Popup or ChildWindow. When the user chooses an item to load, the DataGrid gets loaded with potentially thousands of rows, and the user can't scroll through them easily.

Joshua: what did you do to fix this issue? It might be related to the DataGrid's container, but not necessarily specific to Popup.

Comment: @Zack: I never really got to the bottom of the problem, and I didn't have a virtualized grid, since I only needed to display a dozen or so rows.  I was displaying the grid in a popup, and I had to explicitly reset the DataContext, because I was moving the popup from one page to another.  Long story.  Anyway, I never had this problem when just using a grid on a page in the orthodox way, so I'm not sure how much I can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recoded this, removing some crufty stuff, and the problem went away; see my update.  This isn't really a solution as such, but I wanted to close out the question for the record.